# How does inviting a vampire work with changing flat and tenant?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

In the Buffyverse, vampires cannot enter the residence of a person if not invited. How does this change if the tenant of a residence changes or the tenant has a new residence. Specifically:

1. A vampire is invited to the residence 1 of inhabitant A. Inhabitant A moves to residence 2. Is the vampire still considered invited to residence 2 or does the inhabitant have to reinvite him before being able to enter?
2. A vampire is invited to the residence 1 of inhabitant A. Inhabitant A moves out and a new inhabitant B moves in. Is the vampire still considered invited to the residence 1, even though the inhabitant has changed?

Comment: @Valorum Then what's to stop a vampire from catching some random human out in the open and forcing them to say "I invite you (and all vampires) into all buildings on Earth."?

Comment: @Showsni - Because the human needs to consider the place their residence. A random human wouldn't be able to invite a vamp unless they started living there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're told (in *[Buffy: Real Me](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Real_Me)*) that a vampire can only enter a property when it's invited in by someone that lives there.

> **XANDER:** *Uh, yeah, actually, she -- Harmony -- kind of happened to sort of get an invite.*
>
> **BUFFY:** *You guys can't invite her in. I mean, **only someone who lives here can**-*
>
> Buffy: Real Me

The barrier on the property ceases to function [if and when the human residents die](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/buffy/images/f/f9/AngelLeansOnInvisibleWall.gif) and, critically to your question, **a new barrier is erected if a new set of human occupants takes up residence in a property that was previously accessible to the vampire**, as seen in *[Angel: Heartthrob](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Heartthrob)*, where Angel, who was previously able to do a room-by-room check of the Hyperion, is now suddenly barred from entering Fred's room.

> **Angel:** *I can't come in.*
>
> **Fred:** *Of course not. You're worn from your trip. You go rest. We'll catch up later.*
>
> **Angel:** *Fred, I *want* to talk to you, I just can't come in unless you...*
>
> **Fred:** *I invite you. Instead of being rude! Oh, come in. Come in.*

Note also that mere *ownership or technical residence* of the property isn't sufficient to bar a vampire from entry, as seen in *[Buffy: The Freshman](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/The_Freshman)* where vamps enter Buffy's dorm room freely, as contrasted with *[Buffy: The Yoko Factor](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Yoko_Factor)* where, a few months later, Angel needs an explicit invitation to enter the same room now that she's accepted it as where she lives (**which also addresses your point #1, since he had entry rights to her house in Sunnydale, but not to her dorm room**)